# Adding sound in Blender

Tags: animation

can anybody tell me I tried to add sound effect of a chain falling in the floor in Blender? I tried it many time and it seems I did it in the wrong way! please help.

Comment: You should tell us something more: No sound? sound out of sync? ugly sound? which is your problem? can you give us the .blend file to be analyzed?

Comment: Welcome to the site :) It would help us help you if we knew more about what you tried and what didn't work as expected. Could you add more details about the steps you took and why the results were not what you wanted? Perhaps with a .blend to further demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 8):

Sound can be added in the video sequence editor. Go to the video sequence editor, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, click sound, and select the sound file you want to add.
Remember to change the audio codec, found under the *Encoding* scroll in the *Render* tab, from "none" to one of the other options.
[image]