# How to make a simple one image + music mp4 video?

Tags: video

so, what I want to do is very simple : I'm a music maker/composer (industrial and dark ambient)and I want to upload a track on Youtube.

So, what I have to do is this : have an audio track, and a picture that lasts the time of the track, and export it in a video format (mp4, AVi, whatever). This was extremely easy to do with Windows Movie Maker, but the thing is, there is no Windows Movie Maker on Windows 10. So, I downloaded Blender as it seems to be the best open-source video-editing software around. But, I don't get how am I supposed to do a task that should be so simple :

I go into the video editing screen, I add my track, I add the image, but then what? I don't find how to set the dimension of the image, nor of the video, and have no idea on how to export it as, let's say, a mp4 file.

Any simple tutorial on how to do such a basic thing? 
Thanks

Comment: Blender is meant for video creation, not video editing. It can do video editing as well, but you are simply better off using a different program. Google for "free video editing software".

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32264/adding-sound-in-blender/32275#32275

Comment: @Ezra adding on to this, you can get Movie maker on Windows 10, just Google "Windows Live essential pack".

Answer (score 2):

You can do that even with Blender, although it will not be extremely simple for a program novice. Here is something you need to know:

- you have to create a "sequence", composed by sound track, and an image that is shown for all the sound track length.
- then you have to "render" it, as an "animation" to a video+audio output format
- blender sequences are created as frames, not "seconds": the binding between frames and duration depends on the "animation" frame rate you decide, eg: setting it to 25 f/s would mean that you need

25 f/s * 60 s/minute * 3 minutes = 4500 frames of Blender animation to get a "video" 3 minutes long. You need to tell Blender how many frames your animation needs to be. Later on this.

You can show seconds instead of frames in the "timeline" changing  this setting:

[image]

The output format of an animation can be everything from an image sequence (1 every frame) to a video file container like an .avi, with many codec (as supported by th bundled FFmpeg libraries, so many formats available).

- you set start and end frame in render setting > "frame range"
- you set the frame rate in render settings > "frame rate"
- every frame size will be what you decide in render settings  > "resolution"

[image]

- you set the output folder, filename, container file, video and audio codec in render settings > "output" and "encoding"

[image]

You will need some practice with all this.

I would do:

1. setup desired resolution, frame rate, output and encoding settings
2. switch to video layout and load the audio in a strip, position it so that it starts from frame 1
3. Note its length (eg: 4446 frames) in the right-side edit strip that appears when you select the imported audio strip. You need to tell Blender that your animation will be 4446 frames long
4. set this value in as resolution > frame range > end frame (start frame should be 1 of course), but also in the bottom timeline. This resizes "working area" from the default 250 frames to enough frames to contain all your sound file.

[image]

5. Now add another strip, with the image you choose. This will result in a little strip (a few frames long, just enough to allow you to select it)
6. You need to position the image strip so that's starting at 1 and then extend its end until it reaches last frame of the animation (4446 in the example above). To do this right select the whole little strip, and in the right-side edit strip change its end frame from what it is (eg: 26) to the same last frame of the animation (4446 in the example)
   [image]
7. more or less it should be done: you will end with something like this ( I also show here how you can display the waveform - hint: you could also edit its levels...)

[image]

you just need to tell Blender to "render the animation", that for you will mean "create the video".

[image]

8. It will be slow, compared to similar specialized softwares, but it should work well (this slowness is a small price you have to pay but Blender can - .in the future - allow you, apart this basic video editing usage, more possibilities that only a few expensive other programs can allow you).

I also suggest you to start with shorter frame range (eg enough for a 30 seconds video) to practice.

To be honest, although it could be simpler than it looks, it will need a bit of practice with standard Blender basic commands like grab, zoom. But it is well worth imho, and if you like the workflow, and the possibilities, there is a lot more you can do, it's just a sort of a "primer".

Hth.

Answer (score 1):

A possible alternative way of describing it...

-=====================-

Lay the audio track into the VSE from frame 1.

Lay the image file in another track. (strip)

Highlite the right hand handle at the end of the image strip.

Press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab the handle and move the mouse to the right so it stretches the strip at least to the end of the audio strip. Click the mouse when it's the right length.

[image]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to run it.  It should start playing with the image showing in the top window.

Go up to the top left of the main VSE window, click on "Render" and select "Render Animation"

This will render it out using Blender's Internal render to whatever format you've set it up for at the extreme right. (see attached pic.)