# video editor problems, how can i save an edited video as mp4?

Tags: rendering, export, video-sequence-editor

Could someone help me here please?
I've edited a video in Blender's video editing program but i can't download the file as an mp4. I've looked trough all the answers I could find on the web and on this website, most of them say I should render the video in default mode, but then there's no sound and only the main video without the music and pictures I've added. I'm in this screen now: [image]

Can someone explain me how to download it as an mp4 file or give me an example how I could do it? Any help is appreciated!

Greetings,
Lander

Comment: also see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72547/how-to-make-a-simple-one-image-music-mp4-video/

Comment: I've had problems when rendering to mp4 and now render all videos as H264, AVI and set the sound to mp3, which is the default on my Blender anyway.  I then convert the AVI (which is quite large) to mp4 in an external program (Videopad) with excellent results.